# Connections file change in .pbix file

Tags: powerbi, ssas, analysisservices

I'm facing very weird issue with .pbix file. I have report(s) running on Analysis Services Live Connection. As I have plenty of (same) reports available for many customers, I have a PowerShell sciprt, which is changing connection string automatically (and then deploying).

Connection string is located inside .pbix file named 'Connections'. Everything worked as expected until now. Recently I made Power BI Desktop update (don't know if this could be related), but since then, it's not working anymore.

I tried also to create new blank report and then change connection string, but I'm still getting same error message: 'This file is corrupted or was created by an unrecognized version of Power BI Desktop. It can't be opened.'

I'm opening .pbix with 7zip.
My current Power BI Desktop is: Version: 2.117.984.0 64-bit (May 2023)

Don't you know what could be an issue? Don't you have experience with such problem?

Thanks

Comment: That's the problem when you do unsupported hacks, relying on undocumented behaviour. The right way to do that is to publish your file first, and the use the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources-in-group) to change the connection.